# Android p2p communication

Tags: android, networking

I am developing an application for android that run an RTSP server. The server works fine for the request from a device connected to a same wifi by giving the local IP that is 192.x.x.x but if i send a request by giving the remote IP that is 37.x.x.x the server does not respond.
   My question is that how can i bind my android device with the remote ip so that i can accept request and send response from any device connected to internet. please note that i am using api level 10 as minimum sdk level